# How to use Javascript to get data from a Wordpress form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a booking form using WS Form in Wordpress. Because of the several calculations and conditions accuring when selecting the number of people partecipating in the booking, the form is crazy slow and I've been suggested to use Javascript.

Basically for a numeric field labeled "Adults" and a hypothetical value of 3, I have a separate div that says "Adults number: 3", with the number adjusting according to the field value.

Here is what I tried without success

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// Get the text field by its ID
var textField = document.getElementById('wsf-1-field-13');

// Listen for input event on the text field
textField.addEventListener('input', function() {
    // Get the current value of the text field
    var currentValue = textField.value;

    // Update the HTML editor's content
    document.getElementById('adult-number-display').textContent = currentValue;
});
});
```

where
wsf-1-field-13 is the field ID. In the div I used

```
"Adults number <span id="adult-number-display">1</span>"
```

However the field is never updating. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? that will be more easy in jQuery.

Comment: Well yes. Can you point me in some direction (tutorial on the web, etc...) so that I can learn and try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach should work,

Modify it for your use case.

```
//JQuery Code
jQuery( document ).on( 'change', '.from-this', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '.change-this' ).text( this.value );
} )
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="search" class="from-this" />
<div class="change-this"></div>
```

Comment: That's super. Thanks a lot Syed!